# is it possible to declare a array object type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to declare an array object in typescript like this:

```
export async function getInitialState(): Promise<{
  settings?: Partial<LayoutSettings>;
  currentUser?: API.CurrentUser;
  loading?: boolean;
  dictionary?: Dictionary[];
  fetchUserInfo?: () => Promise<API.CurrentUser | undefined>;
  fetchDictionary?: () => Promise<API.DictionaryList | undefined>;
}> {}
```

but the visual studio shows error:

```
Cannot find name 'Dictionary'.ts(2304)
```

I have already declared Dictionary in context like this:

```
declare namespace API {
  type Dictionary = {
    key,
    value,
    dict_type,
  };
}
```

why still tell that could not found the Dictionary? is it possible to declare an array object type in typescript?

Comment: Probably you should reference the type `Dictionary` like: `Api.Dictionary` since it belongs to the `Api` namespace.

Comment: You can definitely declare array type in typescript, array is not the problem here, you can verify that be removing the array declaration and it would still throw the same error. I'm not very sure why you need a namespace here, but did you export it? Also, within the dictionary type, you should define the type of key, value, and dict_type as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing it's most likely you not exporting the type properly, nothing to do with the array type. If your use-case allows it, try putting it in the same file:

```
type Dictionary = {
    key: string,
    value: string,
    dict_type: string,
};

export async function getInitialState(): Promise<{
  settings?: Partial<LayoutSettings>;
  currentUser?: API.CurrentUser;
  loading?: boolean;
  dictionary?: Dictionary[];
  fetchUserInfo?: () => Promise<API.CurrentUser | undefined>;
  fetchDictionary?: () => Promise<API.DictionaryList | undefined>;
}> {}
```